# Spark-shell command returning \Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I'm trying to set up spark in my local machine. I have followed all steps mentioned in the below link.

https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/

My system installed with Java 1.8. But I'm getting error related to Java 1.7 like below.

[image]

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have Java 8 installed, but your `JAVA_HOME` is still pointing to the old one. Update that variable taking care to handle the spaces with [proper quoting syntax](https://superuser.com/a/452357/120610).

Answer (score 1):

1. JAVA_HOME in your Environment Variables must be something like this: 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` 
   we need to change it some thing like this `C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.8.0_211`
   because there is a space in your path

   2. Once that is done, please close your cmd and reopen it and fire you spark-shell, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try executing spark-shell from bin folder.

c:\spark1.6>bin\spark-shell

Comment: I have tried from bin folder also. It's working for spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6 versions but getting error for spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder where Java is installed in your machine. If it is "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)", you're likely experiencing this issue due to the space in the path.

To resolve this issue:

1. Create a folder with no space like "C:\Java\jre1.8.0_361" and point the installer to this folder
2. Once this installation is complete, navigate to your "Environment Variables" and update your "JAVA_HOME" system variable to point to this location.
3. Reopen your terminal and issue your spark shell commands. This should likely take care of your issue.

Also, please note this will also work for pyspark.